# How to fix implicit conversion warnings?

Tags: c++, c++11, implicit-conversion, unsigned, signed

I'm reading C++ How To Program 9th Edition, trying to learn c++, and attempting the exercise with the Knight's Problem in Chapter 7.

Based on the "64" in the output, the code clearly has some sort of logic error (which I will fix on my own), but before doing this, I'm stuck on understanding and what to do about the compiler warnings.

I've declared board as a two-dimensional array of unsigned int because it can only contain values 0-7. Likewise, I've declared variables in for loops as unsigned int, for the same reason.

I've read responses on stackoverflow about this but they quickly go over my head.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <array>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

void printArray(const array< array< unsigned int, 8 >, 8 >);

int main() {
  array< array< unsigned int, 8 >, 8 > board = {};
  array< int, 8 > horizontal = {{ 2, 1, -1, -2, -2, -1, 1, 2 }};
  array< int, 8 > vertical = {{ -1, -2, -2, -1, 1, 2, 2, 1 }};
  unsigned int currentRow = 0;
  unsigned int currentCol = 0;
  for (unsigned int i = 0; i < 64; i++) {
    board[currentRow][currentCol] = i + 1;
    for (unsigned int j = 0; j < 8; j++) {
      if (currentRow + horizontal[j] >= 0 &&
        currentRow + horizontal[j] < 8 &&
        currentCol + vertical[j] >= 0 &&
        currentCol + vertical[j] < 8 &&
        board[currentRow + horizontal[j]][currentCol + vertical[j]] == 0
      ) {
        currentRow = currentRow + horizontal[j];
        currentCol = currentCol + vertical[j];
        break;
      }
    }
  }
  printArray(board);
}

void printArray(const array< array< unsigned int, 8 >, 8 > myBoard) {
  for ( unsigned int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
    for ( unsigned int j = 0; j < 8; j++) {
      cout << '[' << setw(2) << setfill('0') << myBoard[i][j] << "] ";
    }
    cout << endl;
  }
}
```

Output:

```
~/Programming/cpp/knight => make
rm -fr build/*
clang++ -std=c++11 -stdlib=libc++ -Weverything -Wno-c++98-compat src/main.cpp -o build/main -Isrc/
src/main.cpp:18:24: warning: implicit conversion changes signedness: 'value_type' (aka 'int') to 'unsigned int' [-Wsign-conversion]
      if (currentRow + horizontal[j] >= 0 &&
                     ~ ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
src/main.cpp:18:38: warning: comparison of unsigned expression >= 0 is always true [-Wtautological-compare]
      if (currentRow + horizontal[j] >= 0 &&
          ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ ^  ~
src/main.cpp:19:22: warning: implicit conversion changes signedness: 'value_type' (aka 'int') to 'unsigned int' [-Wsign-conversion]
        currentRow + horizontal[j] < 8 &&
                   ~ ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
src/main.cpp:20:22: warning: implicit conversion changes signedness: 'value_type' (aka 'int') to 'unsigned int' [-Wsign-conversion]
        currentCol + vertical[j] >= 0 &&
                   ~ ^~~~~~~~~~~
src/main.cpp:20:34: warning: comparison of unsigned expression >= 0 is always true [-Wtautological-compare]
        currentCol + vertical[j] >= 0 &&
        ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ ^  ~
src/main.cpp:21:22: warning: implicit conversion changes signedness: 'value_type' (aka 'int') to 'unsigned int' [-Wsign-conversion]
        currentCol + vertical[j] < 8 &&
                   ~ ^~~~~~~~~~~
src/main.cpp:22:28: warning: implicit conversion changes signedness: 'value_type' (aka 'int') to 'unsigned int' [-Wsign-conversion]
        board[currentRow + horizontal[j]][currentCol + vertical[j]] == 0
                         ~ ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
src/main.cpp:22:56: warning: implicit conversion changes signedness: 'value_type' (aka 'int') to 'unsigned int' [-Wsign-conversion]
        board[currentRow + horizontal[j]][currentCol + vertical[j]] == 0
                                                     ~ ^~~~~~~~~~~
src/main.cpp:24:35: warning: implicit conversion changes signedness: 'value_type' (aka 'int') to 'unsigned int' [-Wsign-conversion]
        currentRow = currentRow + horizontal[j];
                                ~ ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
src/main.cpp:25:35: warning: implicit conversion changes signedness: 'value_type' (aka 'int') to 'unsigned int' [-Wsign-conversion]
        currentCol = currentCol + vertical[j];
                                ~ ^~~~~~~~~~~
10 warnings generated.
./build/main
[01] [24] [09] [00] [00] [26] [37] [00]
[10] [41] [02] [25] [36] [00] [00] [27]
[23] [08] [11] [40] [21] [38] [00] [00]
[64] [03] [22] [35] [00] [00] [28] [00]
[07] [12] [05] [20] [39] [34] [00] [00]
[04] [17] [14] [31] [00] [29] [00] [00]
[13] [06] [19] [16] [33] [00] [00] [00]
[18] [15] [32] [00] [30] [00] [00] [00]
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The compiler is saying to you that when you write

```
currentRow + horizontal[j] >= 0
```

you're adding a `signed int` with an `unsigned int`, so the `signed int` is converted in an `unsigned int`, and so the result of the sum is an `unsigned int`. An `unsigned int` is always greater than or equal to zero.

So this test is always `true` which is presumably not exactly what you desire.

Same problem with

```
currentCol + vertical[j] >= 0
```

and more generally, for every sum of `signed`/`unsigned` values.

One option is to define `currentRow` and `currentCol` as (`signed`) `int`.

Otherwise you could cast `unsigned` values appropriately when adding them to `signed` values

```
int{currentRow} + horizontal[j] >= 0
```

Comment: You know, that's one thing I didn't try yet. I'll give it a go. I know I'm missing something here, but it does seem counter-intuitive to do that for variables that will never hold negative values.

Comment: Changing currentRow and currentCol to int reduced the warnings to 4, all of them being: implicit conversion changes signedness: 'int' to 'size_type'

Comment: @TimothyB. - seem counter-intuitive to me too but, in general, try to avoid operations between object of different types and, moreover, signedness; mixing `signed` and `unsigned` values is often cause of big headaches.

Comment: Alternatively you can use static_cast<int>(currentRow) + horizontal[j] >= 0, but as @max66 said be careful when working with different types.